# Android - Insert operation in Create Table - null object reference error

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

So, I managed to create a database handler using tutorials found throughout the internet.

Here's a snippet for the insertion operation

```
public ChosenParkingSlot createSlot(String slot) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.CHOSEN_SLOT_NAME, slot);
        long insertId = database.insert(ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT, null,
            values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT,
            allColumns, ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.CHOSEN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
            null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ChosenParkingSlot newSlot = cursorToSlot(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newSlot;
      }
```

`allColumns` contains :

```
private String[] allColumns = { 
            ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.CHOSEN_ID,
            ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.CHOSEN_SLOT_NAME };
```

And here's how I call it in the class

```
ChosenSlotDAO chosenSlotDAO = new ChosenSlotDAO(this);

        chosenSlotDAO.createSlot(slotA);

        TextView arriveA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.arriveView);

        arriveA.setText(chosenSlotDAO.getSlot());
```

So basically I want to display a single value from a two column table called chosen_parking_slot through a `TextView` called arriveA. But I got an error

`06-11 12:57:32.939: E/AndroidRuntime(10108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.km.parkit/com.km.parkit.ParkAArrive}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference`

What am I missing here??

Comment: Have you initialised your `database` object?

Comment: Yess, it's before onCreate, `private SQLiteDatabase database;`.. Wait.. Initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first initialize your `database` object, before you could insert or do what you want with it. I think that now you just have only the declaration of it ( `SQLiteDatabase database;` ), not the whole initialization like `SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` for example. More info -> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Ohh whole initialization.. Can you please show me an example? I thought I've initialized it in the database handler class using `private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
 + TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT + " ( "
 + CHOSEN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
 + CHOSEN_SLOT_NAME + " text not null " + ");";`

Comment: this what you did is to create it, but in other classes if you want to use it, you should initialize an object from the SQLiteDatabase class and to do it , you need to have a dbHelper that extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class (I think you have one of it, because you have a create method, which usualy is in it). Here you could find a very good whole example of SQLiteDatabase http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Or if you learn better from a video tutorial, I recommend you this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxvfgVuumHU&list=PLF4lVL1sPDSllEYwsMcmNutAe1YFRnSmq&index=25 because everything is shown step by step

Comment: That's the exact tutorial I've copied the codes in my app! Ahahahahaa.. And yes I have the helper renamed to `ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler`.. So I should initialize it like `ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler chosenSlotDatabaseHandler = new ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler(this);` in other class?

Comment: The CRUD operation is stored in another class though.. Not the Handler class but the DAO class as followed from vogella..

Comment: when you have the helper class, you only need to add the `database = chosenSlotDatabaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();` to the class where you want to use the database

Comment: You...... Sir....... Are a lifesaver! Yesssssssssssss, so all this time, it was all because of `database = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();` (or Writable) thingy! Thank you! Now I only need to know why TextView isn't showing the value -.-

Comment: You're welcome :)) What is the problem with the textView? what does it show currently? Does `chosenSlotDAO.getSlot()` return a string?

Comment: Currently tinkering with it, it's supposed to show value taken from the database.. But now it's showing nothing.. I'll make another question about this :D

Comment: Aww, I can only post once in every 90 mins, so, will click that post button in like.. 30 mins~ :D